# Can't include standard headers in C++ Modules (clang++ v12)

Tags: c++, module, clang, clang++, c++20

I'm trying to include standard headers like  in a C++ module. The C++ Clang v12 compiler can't see these headers, but they are found in the old style translation units. Can someone explain how to include the standard headers in C++20 module translation units.

I using clang++ v12, from source, built on Ubuntu 20.

Thanks in advance.

Here's a code sample:

**File: audio.cpp**

```
    // compiler not seeing this include    
    #include <iostream> 
    
    export module audio;
    
    export int init(int fir, int sec){
        ...
    }
```

**clang++ compiler flags:**

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules -stdlib=libc++  -pedantic -Wall -fmodules-ts -c audio.cpp  -Xclang -emit-module-interface -o audio.pcm
```

**Complete compiler error:**

```
 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Modules ****
make all 
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules -stdlib=libc++  -pedantic -Wall -fmodules-ts -c audio.cpp  -Xclang -emit-module-interface -o audio.pcm
audio.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:16: audio.pcm] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the exact error you get? [Edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the error output.

Comment: I [can't replicate it](https://godbolt.org/z/qv56db), so it's possible your installation is incomplete?

Comment: I believe that is the problem. Standard C includes are found but the standard C++ headers are not. There are include directories for clang: 
/usr/include/clang/10 
/usr/include/clang/10/ I thought a 12 directory would be here also because I'm using clang++ v12.

Comment: AFAIK clang doesn't ship with its own standard headers.

Comment: If you remove the `-stdlib=libc++` flag, does it work then? Have you installed or built libc++?

Comment: Yes, I installed libc++. It does work if I remove -stdlib=libc++ but it segfaults when I run it.

Comment: The C functions like puts() are picked up by iostream and they don't segfault when I call them.